# recognize CTRL keydown without input

Tags: angularjs, button, keypress, ctrl

I making a multi select list. On item click it toggles a certain class on that item. I would like to implement multiple selection while <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is down.
Is this possible?

Comment: Show what you have tried (of course it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

The ctrlkey property of your event will evaluate to true if the control key is down when it's called. So basically something like:

```
if (e.ctrlkey) {
    your code
}
```

Update: In answer to your question in the comments, yes. The event object is pretty robust and exposes a number of properties that you can use to determine the type of event you're dealing with, how it was triggered and so on. This is a pretty decent and concise writeup on the event object: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/events-and-javascript-part-3-the-event-object.html.

Comment: Can event be triggered with only CTRL key? Can you combine it with mouseup, mousedown?